# Update OpenSSH on RHEL 5.5

Tags: rhel, openssl, openssh

I must update OpenSSH on my RHEL 5.5 because of CVE-2018-15473. My OpenSSH version is OpenSSH_4.3p2 and must be update to OpenSSH_7.9, when i want to do this i get that message when using configure command

```
checking OpenSSL library version... configure: error: OpenSSL >= 1.0.1 required (have "0090802f (OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008)")
```

so i download OpenSSL_1.0.1a and try to install it, when i use *make test* command

after ***./config*** and ***make*** i get that error at the end

```
error
make[1]: ** [test_cms] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/u01/install/openssl-1.0.1p/test'
make: ** [tests] Error 2***
So... How can i update my OpenSSL and then update OpenSSH???
```

I cant connect my linux os to internet

Comment: The error(s) that you omitted above test_cms are the ones that answerers would need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with the below string of commands:

Download the latest version of the OpenSSL source package:

`wget ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz`

Install OpenSSL 2 & openssh-7.9p1:

1. `tar xzvf openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz`
2. `tar -zxvf openssh-7.9p1.tar.gz`
3. `cd openssl-1.0.2p`
4. `./config shared zlib`
5. `make install`
6. `mv /usr/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl.OFF`
7. `mv /usr/include/openssl /usr/include/openssl.OFF`
8. `ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl`
9. `ln -s /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl /usr/include/openssl`
10. `echo "/usr/local/ssl/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf`
11. `ldconfig -v`
12. `openssl version`
13. `cd openssh-7.9p1`
14. `/configure --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl`
15. `make`
16. `make install`
17. `sshd -version`